# Merging data frames, highlighting the problematic column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to merge two data frames with the aim of finding the value that causes the merging error. Most of the columns are not common across both data frames.

The following highlights what rows have a "NaN" value, how can I then find what column caused the merging issue? Thanks

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='outer')
df4 = (df3[df3.isnull().any(axis=1)])
```

Comment: What is the error?  And what do the DataFrames looks like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is difficult to tell from the question, but the question indicates `pd.merge(df1, df2, on=None, how='outer')`

If `on` is None and not merging on indexes then this defaults to the intersection of the columns in both DataFrames.

This means that the intersection of the columns in both `DataFrame`s better have the same type.  If not, an error will occur indicating a type issue.

```
ValueError: You are trying to merge on int64 and object columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat
```

Presupposing there is a conflict of type interfering with the outer join, the difference between the types of the intersecting columns should be examined.

```
dtypes_diff = pd.concat([df1.dtypes,df2.dtypes]).drop_duplicates(keep=False)
```